# In Google Sheets how to reference infinite columns in all rows?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

The issue of how to reference infinite rows is already answered, but how about referencing infinite columns?

For example Sheet1 has data with an indeterminate number of rows and columns, Sheet2 I have this formula

```
=arrayformula(if(Sheet1!A:Z="","blank","not blank"))
```

It goes infinitely down... but what if I want Sheet1!A:InfiniteColumns

This is the best I could come up with

```
=arrayformula(if(indirect("sheet1!R1C1:"&"R"&rows(Sheet1!A:A)&"C"&COLUMNS(Sheet1!1:1),false)="","blank","not blank"))
```

So my question is, is there a shorter and simpler way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A1:"&ROWS(Sheet1!A:A))="", "blank", "not blank"))
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this sample will get all columns from row 1 to row 1:

```
=arrayformula(if(Sheet1!A1:1="","blank","not blank"))
```

So for infinite columns we can take all columns from row 1 to last row:

```
=arrayformula(if({indirect("MainSheet!1:" & rows(MainSheet!A:A))}="","blank","not blank"))
```